# ListBox ItemsSource WPF Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, listbox, itemssource

I'm not understanding something about binding. I have a `DataTemplate` for type Object which is working, but in there I want to make another `ListBox` and set the data to that of one of the properties of an Object. I've been using Snoop to look at the data context and the data context of the `ListBox` in the Object `DataTemplate` is an Object, but there is an error with the `ItemsSource` and I don't know why. I'm doing `ItemsSource={Binding componentList, Mode=TwoWay}` and an Object has a componentList and componentList is an `ObservableList`. What am I missing?

Here's my XAML code:

```
<Window.Resources>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type properties:Component}">
  <StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="TEST COMPONENT" />
    <ListBox DataContext="{Binding propertyList}" ItemsSource="{Binding propertyList}" />
  </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type properties:Object}">
  <StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="TEST OBJECT" />
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding componentList, Mode=TwoWay}" />
  </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>

</Window.Resources>
```

And my C# code:

```
public class Component
{
  public string name;
  public ObservableCollection<IProperty> propertyList;
}

public class Object
{
  public UnsignedProperty objectID;
  public ObservableCollection<Component> componentList;
}
```

I make a `ListBox` in code and set it's `ItemsSource` to a list of Objects and that's seeing my Object `DataTemplate`, but that's where it stops

```
ListBox properties = new ListBox();
ObservableCollection<Properties.Object> t = new ObservableCollection<Properties.Object>();
t.Add(selectedObject); //potentially more objects
properties.ItemsSource = t;
PropertyPane.Content = properties;
```

any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: you have to user CLR properties in your bindings , 
what you have are fields , componentList with a Setter  and Getter.

Comment: wow, I knew it'd be something so easy. Thanks! that made everything fall perfectly into place. Do you actually need DependancyProperties? or just a get; and set;?

Comment: DependancyProperties are the usually the Target Content is the DP where as any this you bind to it from you DataContext is a CLR property. 

only DP's can be binding Targets , though they can also be a Binding source. 

regular CLR properties can only by a binding source.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to my comments above:

You don't have to create a `ListBox` in code, create it in XAML and bind a collection to your `ItemsSource` (Dependency Property).

Like so:

C#:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;

        Components.Add(new Object());
        Components.Add(new Object());
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Object> components;
    public ObservableCollection<Object> Components
    {
        get
        {
            if (components == null)
                components = new ObservableCollection<Object>();
            return components;
        }
    }
}
```

XAML :

```
<Window>   
   <Grid>
      <ListBox  ItemsSource="{Binding Components, Mode=OneWay}" />        
   </Grid>        
</Window>
```

In addition here is a continuation of your code:

C#:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;

        ListBox properties = new ListBox();
        ObservableCollection<Object> t = new ObservableCollection<Object>();
        t.Add(new Object()); //potentially more objects
        properties.ItemsSource = t;
        PropertyPane.Content = properties;
    }        
}

public interface IProperty
{
}

public class Component
{
    public string name;

    private ObservableCollection<IProperty> propertyList;
    public ObservableCollection<IProperty> PropertyList
    {
        get
        {
            if (propertyList == null)
                propertyList = new ObservableCollection<IProperty>();
            return propertyList;
        }
    }
}

public class Object
{
    private ObservableCollection<Component> componentList;
    public ObservableCollection<Component> ComponentList 
    {
        get
        {
            if (componentList == null)
                componentList = new ObservableCollection<Component>();
            return componentList;
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Component}">
          <StackPanel>
              <TextBlock Text="TEST COMPONENT" />
              <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding PropertyList, Mode=OneWay}" />
          </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>

      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Object}">
          <StackPanel>
              <TextBlock Text="TEST OBJECT" />
              <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ComponentList, Mode=OneWay}" />
          </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
```